# Redis is very slow on Digital Ocean , queried from Python Redis

Tags: python, redis

I have a database using Redis on Digital Ocean that is very slow.
I have Kubernetes running some random queries on a 1mio set of data.
This is an example of Key I have `ETHUSDT:1654903478350:851334981` as `Crypto:TimeStamp:TradeId`.
And an example of Data:
`"{"1654903478350":"{\"e\":\"trade\",\"E\":1654903478350,\"s\":\"ETHUSDT\",\"t\":851334981,\"p\":\"1661.71000000\",\"q\":\"2.18090000\",\"b\":9209342396,\"a\":9209342326,\"T\":1654903478347,\"m\":false,\"M\":true}"}"`

I am using Redis Python to connect as follow:

```
r = redis.Redis(host="db-redis-EXAMPLE-do-user-113414-0.b.db.ondigitalocean.com",
                port=25061,
                username="default",
                password="PASSWORD",
                ssl=True, ssl_cert_reqs=None)
```

Running the following code takes up to two minutes which seems slow, there is about 45K results to get from the database:

```
subselect = redis_conn.scan_iter("LUNAUSDT:*:*")
p = redis_conn.pipeline()
for key in subselect:
    p.hgetall(key)
k = p.execute()
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to increase the speed is to specify the argument Count and increase it to a larger value.